# Property CWebApplication.Cookies is not defined

Tags: php, cookies, yii, yii-components

I am using  [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/591/yii-use-arrays-in-cookies-a-helper-class-for-using-arrays-in-cookies/) to use the cookies functionality in yii framework.
When I accessed the application in localhost it gives following error:

```
Property CWebApplication.Cookies is not defined.
```

Please help me guys that where I am doing mistake.

I have included

`'Cookies' => array (
            'class' => 'application.components.CookiesHelper'
    ),`

in config->main.php and i am trying to use the function `putCMsg`
as follows

`$this->putCMsg('someCookieName','SomeValue');`

But this error comes on this line of index.php

`Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();`

Comment: Please add more details including the code segment you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Creating cookie in `config/main.php` is not a good solution. It's better to set cookie in the controller's action like this:

```
$cookie = new CHttpCookie('someCookieName','SomeValue');
$cookie->expire = 200000; //times in milliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
adding any component as an array doesn't mean that i am creating object of that class. It simply means that i am saying that just go to this package to pick something.
I am comfortable to use the way you have mentioned in your answer but i want to use by declaring it into component folder or helper folder as discussed in the link i have mentioned in my question
Thanks.